# foreign language translation dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, translation

I am trying to compile a dictionary on Python of new words which I have learnt. The program will then test my knowledge of the words by asking me to translate random keys from the dictionary.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
import random

witcher_dic =  {'bridles' : 'уздцы'  , 'hum' : 'гул' , 'to become deserted' : 'опустеть', 'linen' : 'полотяный' , 'apron' : 'фартук' ,
               'pockmarked (object)' : 'щербатый' , 'quiver (arrow)' : 'колчан' , 'to take a sip' : 'обхлебнуть' ,
               'to grunt' : 'буркнуть' , 'vile/foul' : 'паскудный' , 'pockmarked (person)' : 'рябой' , 'big-man' : 'верзила' ,
               'punk' : 'шпана' , 'to bark (person)' : 'гархнуть' , 'bastard, premature child' : 'недосонок' ,
               'to mumble' : 'промямлить' , 'to bark (person2)' : 'рявкнуть' , 'to look around oneself' : 'озираться' ,
               'oliquely' : 'наискось' , 'a mess/fuss' : 'кутерьма' , 'bolt (sound)' : 'грохот' , 'to blink' : 'шмяхнуться' ,
               'dissected' : 'рассеченный' , 'to wriggle' : 'извиваться', 'tender/sensitive' : 'чуткий' , 'to hang to' : 'облепить',
               'a clang/clash' : 'лязг' , 'to snuggle up to' : 'прильнуть' , 'boot-leg' : 'голенищ' , 'stuffing' : 'набивки' ,
               'cuffs' : 'манжеты' , 'to jump up' : 'вскочить' , 'to dart off' : 'помчаться' , 'to scream' : 'заволить' , 'shrilly' : 'пронзительно',
               'to back away' : 'пятиться' , 'loaded (horse)' : 'навьюченный'}


def ranWord():
    word = random.choice(list(witcher_dic.keys()))
    return word

while True:

    print(ranWord())
    guess = input('Please enter the translation for this word: ')
    if guess == witcher_dic[word]:
        print('Well done!')
    else:
        input(print('Please try again: '))

input('Press any key to exit')
```

Apologies for format and indentation but am new to stackoverflow and still learning the ropes!

I suppose the problem is on the line: if guess == witcher_dic[word]

The program should match the user entry to the dictionary value.

Comment: Can you provide example input/output with the desired behavior? Are you sure you are entering the correct casing of the word? (i.e. `Word` vs `word`)

Comment: Well, what *is* the problem? I need more information to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems with your code.

1.) to use non ascii characters you need to declare the encoding with a "magic" comment
2.) `ranWord` only defines `word` in its own scope so you cant use it outside the function. I would recommend learning about scope
3.) `input(print(str))` is invalid syntax. use `input(str)`
4.) this is not really a problem but you never exit the while loop so you would be translating words forever. You can decide how you want handle that

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#include these!^

import random

witcher_dic =  {'bridles' : 'уздцы'  , 'hum' : 'гул' , 'to become deserted' : 'опустеть', 'linen' : 'полотяный' , 'apron' : 'фартук' ,
               'pockmarked (object)' : 'щербатый' , 'quiver (arrow)' : 'колчан' , 'to take a sip' : 'обхлебнуть' ,
               'to grunt' : 'буркнуть' , 'vile/foul' : 'паскудный' , 'pockmarked (person)' : 'рябой' , 'big-man' : 'верзила' ,
               'punk' : 'шпана' , 'to bark (person)' : 'гархнуть' , 'bastard, premature child' : 'недосонок' ,
               'to mumble' : 'промямлить' , 'to bark (person2)' : 'рявкнуть' , 'to look around oneself' : 'озираться' ,
               'oliquely' : 'наискось' , 'a mess/fuss' : 'кутерьма' , 'bolt (sound)' : 'грохот' , 'to blink' : 'шмяхнуться' ,
               'dissected' : 'рассеченный' , 'to wriggle' : 'извиваться', 'tender/sensitive' : 'чуткий' , 'to hang to' : 'облепить',
               'a clang/clash' : 'лязг' , 'to snuggle up to' : 'прильнуть' , 'boot-leg' : 'голенищ' , 'stuffing' : 'набивки' ,
               'cuffs' : 'манжеты' , 'to jump up' : 'вскочить' , 'to dart off' : 'помчаться' , 'to scream' : 'заволить' , 'shrilly' : 'пронзительно',
               'to back away' : 'пятиться' , 'loaded (horse)' : 'навьюченный'}


def ranWord():
    word = random.choice(list(witcher_dic.keys()))
    return word

while True:
    wrd = ranWord()
    print(wrd)
    guess = input('Please enter the translation for this word: ')
    if guess == witcher_dic[wrd]:
        print('Well done!') # maybe break here after a certain amount correct?
    else:
        input('Please try again: ') #or instead of trying again you can just lose when you answer incorrectly

input('Press any key to exit')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Working smoothly now!

Comment: @karaganda No problem! If this answers your question consider accepting it by clicking the green check underneath the votes!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems I can see:

1. The result of the call to ranWord is not saved anywhere. You use `word` a bit later on but it will not be defined. You should do `word = ranWord()` and then something like `guess = input(f'Please enter the translation for {word}: ')`.
2. If the player guesses correctly, the loop continues anyway. Add a `break` statement to terminate the loop after printing `Well done!`.
3. The `Please try again` line seems unnecessary; when the loop restarts it will prompt the player for a new guess. Remove the `else`, or replace the second `input` call with `print(Your guess was incorrect.)`.